# Oracle Apex 5 interactive report blob image display

Tags: image, oracle, blob, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am Having a apex application already available in **Oracle APEX 4**. Which is working fine.

Now i am trying to migrate to the same apex application to **APEX 5**.

After migrating some of the functionalities working fine in **Apex 4** are not working in apex 5 like

1. Displaying Blob images from a DB Table as Icon in interactive report in apex 5.

I am using the below query to display image in interactive report

```
select
apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P16_IMAGE', image_id) as icon_image from image_table
```

inside my application under the list view i am getting a URL generated by the **apex_util.get_blob_file_src** when i try to access the below link i am getting the error in the browser

http://server-info/apex/apex_util.get_blob_file?a=107&s=3797597566580&p=16&d=299222323103903080&i=299221224544903071&p_pk1=621333&p_pk2=&p_ck=P7Pek2qEnfoo5FBbvmqn4SQ-ymA&p_content_disposition=inline

**Error from the Browser :**

```
Not found

The requested URL /apex/apex_util.get_blob_file was not found on this server
```

please let me know whether any specific settings need to be done for the Apex 5 Interactive report to display icon image.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, Inside the region definition, Embed the function call within an image tag to display it as an image on the interactive report.

```
SELECT '<img src="'||APEX_UTIL.GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC('P16_IMAGE',image_id,null,'inline')
||'" height="100" width="140"/>' as IMAGE_DISPLAY FROM IMAGE_TABLE
```

This would enable you to control the width and size of the images as well.

Secondly, on the report attributes, make sure to have the display type as **"Standard Report Column"**.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to use RESTful services where you reference the img URL in the IR column HTML expression. e.g.,

Check this:
http://krisrice.blogspot.ae/2013/07/using-restful-to-deliver-images-for-apex.html

Even if you want to stick to GET_BLOB, it is recommended to remove all HTML tags from the SQL query to the column HTML expression.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to show Blob Image in Interactive Report.

### Set the Static ID of Blob "PIC_ID" and Copy following in Inline CSS

td[headers="PIC_ID"] img {   display: block;   width: 40px;   border: 1px solid #999;   padding: 4px;   background: #f6f6f6; }

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.